# when should I escape the sql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Referring to [CodeIgniter Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html).

There are many functions that accept an optional `$escape` parameter, defined as:

> $escape (bool) – Whether to escape values and identifiers

In what situation should or should not escape?

Comment: You should always escape values and identifiers unless you've sanitized the input in advance.

Comment: The only exception would be when none of the inputs come from the user.

Comment: @shmosel,DFriend , thanks. I understood now.

Comment: @DFriend Just because they're not from the user doesn't mean they don't need to be escaped.

Comment: @DFriend One example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_order_SQL_injection.

Comment: @chris85, You make a very good point. I stand corrected. Perhaps the moral of the story is that "user input" is not only from POST / GET but should also previously supplied inputs retrieved from the database. It also points out the importance of proper data sanitization. Escaping input values is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually explained in the link that you have provided:

> If you are using a database that CodeIgniter escapes queries for, you
>   can prevent escaping content by passing an optional third argument,
>   and setting it to FALSE.

It means; for example MySQL is supported and it will escape:

```
$this->db->having('user_id',  45);  // Produces: HAVING `user_id` = 45 in some databases such as MySQL
```

for disabling it:

```
$this->db->having('user_id',  45, FALSE);  // Produces: HAVING user_id = 45
```

But your question was when to use `FALSE` argument right? So let me give you a scenario for usage of `FALSE` argument from [the old documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html):

```
$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.invoice_id=4') AS amount_paid', FALSE);
```

> This (FALSE) is useful if you need a compound select statement.

Without `FALSE` it will produce:

```
SELECT `(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.invoice_id=4`
```

but with `FALSE`:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(payments.amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.invoice_id=4
```

and the desired case is the last one. Using  `FALSE` is simply removes backticks (`).

This kind of usages is preferred because it's practical to write but I do not recommend it because it's confusing.

I prefer to write like this:

```
<?php
    .
    .
    $whatever_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT (SELECT SUM(payments.amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.invoice_id=4 '.$whatever_query);
?>
```

But there are people prefer to use: `$this->db->select()` and this is why there is a `FALSE` argument.

By the way it's not a `$this->db->select()` specific issue. There could be many cases need to use `FALSE` argument when calling other query builder functions. But the common keyword of such cases is probably **compound statement**.